# Ajax, limitar tempo mesmo dando reload na página

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Tenho o código que faz o que tem que fazer, e ao terminar ele esconde o botão e mostra a mensagem de sucesso:

```
function getFollow() {
  $('#btnFollow').click(function(a) {

    a.preventDefault(), $('#btnFollow').html('Ganhando seguidores...');

    $.ajax({
      url: 'api/follow.php',
      dataType: 'JSON',
      success: function(a) {
        1 == a.error ? alert(a.message) : (
          $('.success').css('display', 'block'),
          $('.success').html(a.message),
          setTimeout(function () {
              $('#btnFollow').hide();
          }, 2e3)
        )
      }
    })
  });
}

getFollow();
```

O problema é que ao atualizar a página o botão volta e a mensagem some, na mensagem está escrito o seguinte: **"Seguidores enviados com sucesso, volte em 30 minutos."**

Gostaria que após 30 minutos o botão voltasse automaticamente, sem atualizar a página, e se atualizar antes dos 30 minutos a mensagem continua lá. Como faze-lo de forma correta?

**EDIT**

Follow.php

```
<?php

require_once dirname(__DIR__) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'autoload.php';
require_once dirname(__DIR__) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'helpers' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'TwitterOAuthHelper.php';

$helper = new TwitterOAuthHelper;

$twitterusers = new TwitterUsers;



if ($user = $helper->signedIn()) {
    $fetch = $twitterusers->selectUser($user->screen_name);

    foreach ($fetch as $row) {
        $screen_name[] = $row['screen_name'];
    }

    if ($followers = $helper->getFollowers($screen_name)) {
        echo json_encode([
            "error" => "Algo deu errado!",
            "success" => '',
            "message" => "Seguidores enviados com sucesso, volte em 30 minutos."
        ]);
    }
} else {
    echo json_encode([
            "error" => "true",
            "message" => "You have no open session."
        ]
    );
}
```

Comment: Você pode utilizar $_COOKIE para tratar OU pode tratar através do IP do usuário OU ainda pode tratar através do id do usuário que retorna em "$helper->signedIn()"

Comment: @Everson, tentei colocar em prática, porém minha lógica não combinou com a tua, tem algum exemplo mínimo? , eu postaria meu código aqui mas excluí....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você precisa chamar `api/follow.php` também no onready da página; ou seja ao recarregar a página ele verifica novamente o status de tempo e esconde ou não o seu botão.

```
VerificarSeguidores = function(){
    $.ajax({
            url: 'api/follow.php',
            dataType: 'JSON',
            success: function(a) {
                1 == a.error ? alert(a.message) : (
                $('.success').css('display', 'block'),
                $('.success').html(a.message),
                setTimeout(function(){
                    $('#btnFollow').hide();
                }, 2e3))
            }
    }); 
}


/* Quando a página carregar verifica o status de seguidores 
e omite ou não o botão.*/
$(document).ready(function() {
    /* O código incluído no interior $( document ).ready() só será executado 
    uma vez que a página Document Object Model (DOM) 
    esteja pronta para o código JavaScript para executar.*/
    VerificarSeguidores();      
});

/*Quando houver o evento clique sobre o botão executa verificações de 
seguidores.*/
$('#btnFollow').click(function(a){
    a.preventDefault(), $('#btnFollow').html('Ganhando seguidores...');
    VerificaSeguidores();
});
```

Após isso para monitorar o tempo decorrido, se é maior que 30 minutos. Você poderia guardar um cookie com a data e hora de entrada do usuário na página, e utilizando `setInterval` verificar de tempos em tempos quanto minutos foram decorridos. Se maior que 30 minutos chama-se novamente a rotina ajax e libera o botão. O cookie evitaria de ficar enviando requisições desnecessárias para o servidor.

Comment: Pow, valeu pela resposta, eu testarei mais tarde blz? agora estou de saída, provavelmente estarei aqui a noite. aí testarei

Comment: Tranquilo, a noite vôce testa com calma.

Comment: Opa, deu pra testar aqui rapidinho, vou sair só meio dias mesmo, mas não funcionou e não mostra erros.

Comment: Seria bom colocar também um exemplo de uso do `setInterval` para responder melhor a questão @RafaelSalomão

Answer (score 2):

Você pode usar cookies, algo como:

```
function getFollow() {
    $('#btnFollow').click(function(a) {

        a.preventDefault(), $('#btnFollow').html('Ganhando seguidores...');

        $.ajax({
            url: 'api/follow.php',
            dataType: 'JSON',
            success: function(a) {
                if (a.error == 1) {
                    alert(a.message)
                } else {

                    $('.success').css('display', 'block');
                    $('.success').html(a.message);
                    var expires = new Date();
                    expires.setTime(expires.getTime() + (30*60*1000));
                    document.cookie = "esconderBotao='" + a.message + "'; expires=" +  expires.toUTCString() + "; path=/";
                    setTimeout(function () {
                            $('#btnFollow').hide();
                    }, 2e3);
                    setTimeout(verificaCookie, (30*60*1000));

                }
            }
        })
    });
}

getFollow();

// original em https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp
function getCookie(cname) {
    var name = cname + "=";
    var decodedCookie = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);
    var ca = decodedCookie.split(';');
    for(var i = 0; i <ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
            c = c.substring(1);
        }
        if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
            return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
        }
    }
    return "";
}

function verificaCookie() {
    var msg = getCookie('esconderBotao');
    if(msg != "") {
        // pagina recarregou mas cookie nao expirou
        $('#btnFollow').hide();
        $('.success').css('display', 'block');
        $('.success').html(msg);
        // verifica novamente em 1 minuto
        setTimeout(verificaCookie, 60 * 1000);
    } else {
        $('#btnFollow').show();
        $('.success').css('display', 'none');

    }
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    // ao carregar verifica cookie
    verificaCookie();
})
```

Comment: mas se o usuário limpar os cookies ele pode usar novamente?

Comment: está funcionando porém, `'NaNfunction toUTCString() { [native code] }` o que quer dizer este erro ?

Comment: Realmente se o usuário limpar os cookies ele consegue reutilizar o sistema de novo. só uma correção `var cookie = getCookie('hideButton');
    if(cookie != "") {
        var msg = "Seguidores enviados com sucesso, volte em 30 minutos.";` Pra evitar aquela mensagem que citei a cima.

Comment: Esse código não funciona, fiz de tudo pra arrumar, cookies não expiram, está com erros, ou seja, não serviu!

Comment: Corrigi os erros, pergunta: o follow.php dentro dos 30 minutos de espera vai retornar error == 1 e após error == 0?

Comment: bom vou colocar meu arquivo follow.php pra vc ver.

Comment: Editei a pergunta

Comment: Aproveitando o tópico, se puder me ajudar na contagem de seguidores recebidos em tempo real... e também na mensagem, ir caindo por exemplo "aguarde 30, depois aguarde 29" entendeu ?

Answer (score 1):

Como comentei, você pode definir de várias maneiras. Umas são um pouco mais seguras e outras menos, isso dependerá de sua necessidade.

Código base para as alterações:

```
<?php

require_once dirname(__DIR__) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'autoload.php';
require_once dirname(__DIR__) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'helpers' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'TwitterOAuthHelper.php';

$helper = new TwitterOAuthHelper;

$twitterusers = new TwitterUsers;

$verificar = $_GET['verificar'];//Verificar se está apenas consultando
if($verificar == 'S'){
   $ret = verify_user_activity('S'); // Realiza a consulta para verificar se pode ou não mostrar os botões
   die( ($ret ? 'S' : 'N') ); // S = mostrar botões, N = não mostrar
}

if ($user = $helper->signedIn()) {

    verify_user_activity(); //Verifica se está dentro do prazo, caso algum usuário tente burlar o método.

    $fetch = $twitterusers->selectUser($user->screen_name);

    foreach ($fetch as $row) {
        $screen_name[] = $row['screen_name'];
    }

    if ($followers = $helper->getFollowers($screen_name)) {
        echo json_encode([
            "error" => "false",
            "waiting"=>"false",
            "success" => "true",
            "message" => "Seguidores enviados com sucesso, volte em 30 minutos."
        ]);
    }
} else {
    echo json_encode([
            "error" => "true",
            "waiting"=>"false",
            "success" => "false",
            "message" => "You have no open session."
        ]
    );
}
```

1. Utilizando $_COOKIE para validação

Exemplo:

```
function verify_user_activity( $verify = 'N' ){
    if($verify == 'S'){
       if(!empty($_COOKIE['user_last_activity'])){
            $last_time = $_COOKIE['user_last_activity']; //Pega o timestamp

            //Verifica se passou os 30 min
            if($last_time >= time() ) { 
               return true;
            }else {
               //Gera mensagem
               return false;
            } 
      }else{
         return true; 
      }
    }else{
         //Verifica se existe o COOKIE que guarda o timestamp de quando ele pode realizar novamente o comando
        if(!empty($_COOKIE['user_last_activity'])){
           $last_time = $_COOKIE['user_last_activity']; //Pega o timestamp

           //Verifica se passou os 30 min
           if($last_time >= time() ) { 
              $_COOKIE['user_last_activity'] = strtotime("+30 minutes"); //Atualiza a data
           }else {
               //Gera mensagem
               die json_encode([
                "waiting" => "true",
                "message" => "Você não atingiu o tempo mínimo."
               ]);
           }
        }else{
           $_COOKIE['user_last_activity'] = strtotime("+30 minutes"); //Atualiza a data
        }
    }

}
```

2. Utilizando IP + Banco de dados

Exemplo:

```
 function verify_user_activity( $verify = 'N' ){    
    /**
        Esta solução se baseia em ter uma tabela no banco de dados
        Com as colunas de:
            IP - ip do usuário
            TIMESTAMP - timestamp de quando ele poderá realizar a operação novamente
    */      
    $user_ip = getUserIP(); // Busca o IP do usuário da requisição
    $con = get_conexao_do_banco_da_sua_escolha(); //Gera conexão com o banco de dados
    $last_time = get_timestamp_do_ip_no_db($user_ip,$con); //Busca da tabela através do IP do usuário

    if($verify == 'S'){
       if(empty($last_time)){
          return true; 
       }else{
           if($last_time >= time() ) { 
              return true;
           }else {
              return false;
           }
        }       
    }else{      
        //Se estiver vazio ou não há registro no banco
        if(empty($last_time)){
           $last_time = strtotime("+30 minutes"); //Atualiza a data
           insere_atualiza_data_do_usuario($user_ip,$last_time,$con); //Guarda a informação no banco de dados
        }else{
           if($last_time >= time() ) { 
              $last_time = strtotime("+30 minutes"); //Atualiza a data
              insere_atualiza_data_do_usuario($user_ip,$last_time,$con);//Guarda a informação no banco de dados
           }else {
              //Gera mensagem 
              die json_encode([
               "waiting" => "true",
               "message" => "Você não atingiu o tempo mínimo."
              ]);
           }
        }
    }   
}
```

Agora, vamos ao JavaScript:

Caso o usuário recarregar a página, todos os dados da tela voltam ao estado original, para isso precisará realizar uma requisição inicial para verificar se necessita da aparição do botão ou não.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //Adicionado um parâmetro de verificação
    VerificarSeguidores('V');      
});
```

Com isso necessitará alterar sua função para:

```
VerificarSeguidores = function(verificar){

    if(typeof verificar == 'undefined') verificar = '';

    var returnType = 'json'; 
    if(verificar == 'S') returnType = 'text';

    $.ajax({
            url: 'api/follow.php?verificar='+verificar,
            dataType: returnType,
            success: function(a) {
                if(verificar == 'S'){
                   if(a != 'S'){
                      //Defina a ação para esconder os botões AQUI
                   }else{  /* APARECER OS BOTÕES AQUI */ }
                }else{
                   1 == a.error ? alert(a.message) : ( 
                     1 == a.waiting ? alert('ESTOU AGUARDANDO 30 minutos') : 
                   (
                   $('.success').css('display', 'block'),
                   $('.success').html(a.message),
                   setTimeout(function(){
                       $('#btnFollow').hide();
                   }, 2e3))
                   )
                }
            }
    }); 
}
```

No comentário "//Defina a ação para esconder os botões AQUI", realize o ocultamento do conteúdo que você deseja e configure um tempo para o sistema verificar novamente se pode mostrar ou não o botão.

Answer (score 1):

Existem algumas maneiras de fazer isso, com prós e contras:

**1. Session**

Criando uma session, o cliente não tem como "burlar" porque ela eh criada no servidor. O problema é que você vai ter que ficar fazendo requisições ao servidor de tempo em tempo para ver se a session expirou.

*Pró:* o cliente não pode burlar.
*Contra:* muitas requisições ao servidor pode deixa-lo mais lento.

**2. LocalStorage (JavaScript)**

Criar uma localStorage eu acho melhor do que trabalhar com cookie.

*Pró:* facilidade de uso.
*Contra:* o cliente pode limpar via console.

**3. Cookie**

Se for feito via cliente ou servidor, o usuário pode apagar.

*Pró:* facilidade de manipular (lado servidor. eu particularmente nunca trabalhei com cookie lado cliente).
*Contra:* o cliente pode limpar do navegador.

**Minha opinão:**

Criar uma session no servidor e uma localStorage com os mesmos valores. E ir checando a localStorage de tempo em tempo (ex. de 1 em 1 minuto) e quando for maior que 30 minutos, fazer uma requisição ao servidor para validar a session. Caso os valores sejam iguais, libera o botão. Isso evita que um engraçadinho possa alterar a localStorage :).